# Hibernate annotation Where only apply to 1 to Many relationship?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, where-clause

Good day,

I have a entity file call `Agroup.java`, and I link it to another table call `Bservice.java`, which is 1 to many relationship. So I code it like below:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "Agroup")
    @Where(clause = "deleted = 0")
    public Set< Bservice> getBServices() {
        return BServices;
    }
```

And in the hibernate query, I found that it will add in the `deleted = 0` condition.

```
left outer join Bservice b on a.groupId = b.groupId AND ( b.deleted = 0)"
```

This is working fine.

However, I have another approach, which is Many to 1 relationship, which is Bservice.java link to Cservice.java, I code it as follow:

```
@ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "serviceId", nullable = false)
    @Where(clause = "deleted = 0")
    public Cservice getCService() {
        return CService;
    }
```

This only join the 2 table, but didnt add in the where condition.

```
left outer join Cservice c on b.serviceId = c.serviceId
```

Is it Hibernate annotation Where only apply to 1 to Many relationship?

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your Hibernate version.
The short answer to your question is: No. The `@Where` annotation can be used for `OneToOne` and `ManyToOne` relationships.

Depending on your Hibernate version, the SQL will be generated with the "Where" clause outside of your left outer join clause. Something like this:

> ...left outer join Cservice c on b.serviceId = c.serviceId WHERE
>   b.deleted = 0

Instead of:

> left outer join Bservice b on a.groupId = b.groupId AND ( b.deleted =
>   0)

Have a look at this link from the Hibernate team: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9084

From the official documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association

> It is possible to set
>
> -> the where clause, using @Where (applied on the target entity) or @WhereJoinTable (applied on the association table)

Comment: Thanks. Good knowledge sharing @Bruno Franco. I just checked my sql, the SQL didnt generated with the "Where" clause outisde my left outer join clause. The "Where" function like just gone. Do u have any idea on this? Is it cause by I using `mappedBy` in first case and `JoinColumn` second case?